# Is there any way to fulfill a wish?

Tags: scripture, mantras, prayer, boon

I want to know if there is any way to fulfill a wish per Hindu scripture.

I've seen people saying on the Internet saying that chanting a certain mantra for a specific number of times (10 times, 108 times, 20,000 times) will result in the deity granting their wish within a couple of days.

Is there any way to do this? Does repeated chanting of a mantra result in your wish being granted? If so, what mantra should I use, and how many times should I say it?

Comment: There are some mantras, prayogas, charms for this purpose .. you may want to search on a site called Prophet666 .. but whether those methods indeed work or not has to be verified by us .. no guarantee.

Comment: Mantra purushcharana is one of the ways to obtain the grace of deity in a short period of time.Most simplest one requires you chant the mantra(considering you are not performing any homa/pre&post japa rituals) 125000 times in 40/60/90/120 days subject to stringent rules(celibacy over entire period of sadhana, doing sadhana on the same time everyday, doing the same number of rounds of japa everyday using the same beads everyday, eating only satvic food(no onion&garlic) etc)

Comment: You can check out some related answers to mantra purushcharana on this website... :)

Comment: @Rickross have you used any of thoose

Comment: My final advice is if your looking for some quick fulfilment of any wish you should drop the idea of chanting any mantra.Only selfless devotion is in your hands, results would come anyway if the deity is pleased with your devotion.I have heard of many instances where even after intense sadhana of 2-3 years ppl didn't get any darshan but some just got it in 40 days purushcharana.So you never know.Also Read [this](https://www.spiritualbee.com/posts/dont-be-sad-if-meditation-does-not-yield-immediate-results/) story of Sripad Madhvacharya.My comments may sound harsh i am sorry if they offend you..

Comment: @AbhinavRaj Yes I have used one mantra from that site .. not any wish fulfilling mantra/method ... but a rat repellent mantra which worked like magic. Once rats were creating trouble in our house. We tried traps and every possible methods but nothing worked Then I took a rat repelling Shabar mantra from that site and from that day rats disappeared magically .. so I kind of trust that site.

Comment: Rats repellent omg  I’m reading this convo between you guys and can’t stop lol :D This is one of those things that’s so weirdly specific that you can tell it’s true & No lies detected :D I would like a mantra that helps to look pretty & also gives slightly bigger boobz, I will look and see what I can find haha:D  This site HSE is the bomb though, where else could find such info, & yeah freakin adore this place & you guys hahaha:D ☔️❤️‍

Comment: @Rickross that's kinda funny I will try that but I will surely consult you guys before doing anything

Comment: @veganenvironmentalist mantra to look pretty and bigger boobs hope you find something, I didn't even realize you were a girl all this time

Comment: @Rāmachandra I been trying to fulfil this wish of mine from yrs prayed to God over thousand now I don't have much time I want that thing within 2-3  months that's the time limit I'm willing to do whatever it takes for that

Comment: @AbhinavRaj dear fellow sadhaka mantra sadhana is not the one for quick results.Result centric devotion will not take you anywhere and will yield no result.Unless you are ready to undergo transformation via rigorous discipline and selfless devotion towards the deity any advice is useless....Do you really think God would really listen to your selfish desires just because you did some half-hearted japa for him?

Comment: This is the mantra (https://www.prophet666.com/2011/08/mantra-for-protection-against-rats.html) and it really worked like magic. I never expected that it will be beneficial but it worked when the other methods failed @AbhinavRaj

Comment: Rat repelling Yantras (talisman) are also there .. rats usually won't enter a place where this Yantra is hung (https://www.prophet666.com/2018/07/charm-to-make-mice-run-away.html) @veganenvironmentalist

Comment: @Rickross I've also found a yantra for my purpose let's see what happens                https://www.prophet666.com/2021/11/write-these-9-numbers-on-paper-to.html?m=1

Comment: Nice @AbhinavRaj hopefully following the steps correctly will get your wish fulfilled. For fulfilling desires there is also a Yantra called Sarva Manokamna Ourti Yantra - https://www.amazon.in/Astrodidi-Sarva-Manokamna-Yantra-Pocket/dp/B07N5NKMX2/ref=sr_1_6?keywords=manokamna+yantra&qid=1674898631&sr=8-6

Comment: Sorry its not ourti in the above comment but purti @AbhinavRaj

Comment: What is actually the difference between a wish and a boon?

Comment: @AbhinavRaj did it work? Is your wish fulfilled?

Comment: @Wikash_    Nope I tried but nothing

Comment: Sad too hear you've wasted your time. Are you sure the mantra was correctly chanted?

Answer (score 1):

Try
1)
Giving mala of red flowers to lord Hanuman ji for 40 days to nearby hanuman mandir.

Note :- you should walk on naked feet

After giving mala:- (say your wish)

2)

Gokulnathay namah

Chant this mantra for 108 times.

Note:- this is one time chanting. You don't need to chant again

Warning:-
Dont wish for bad things to happen

W

Comment: Sir can we also do these things for fulfillment of any wish?  And for that mantra which you said, we only need to chant it 108 times only isn't it? And when do we have to ask our wish in that?

Answer (score 0):

Your wishes, i.e. desires to obtain something, are not acheived by any mantra, tantra* or yantra^. Your physical and mental steps towards the fruit of such desires/wishes will get you your wishes. Take it from the OG Adi Shankara himself -

**[Viveka ChoodAmaNi](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookVivekChudamaniByGitaPress/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater)**

***Chittasya shuddhaye karma, na tu vastu-upalabdhaye;
vastu-siddhi vichAreNa, na kinchit karma kOtibhi hi!***

**Meaning**: *Karma kAryAs** results only in cleansing of your subconsciousness (mind), but not in your acheiving any pursuit; inquiring into/about the fruit of your desires/wishes will result in your acheiving your wishes; but even a crore/10 million karma kAryAs also will not help you get even an miniscule part of your wishes.

*: pooja, vratha, homa, yajna, abhishekam, shravana, naama smarana, sankeertana, pada seva, dAsyam, archana, vandana, sakhyam, Atma nivedana or even anjali.

^: a created-or-naturally occuring object, such as your cell phone, watch, gadgets, gemstones, rings of all kinds, taslimans, etc.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -2):

The mantras will be helpful to attract the universe to give what you are trying to manifest, however for example if you are blindly reciting mantra without action is not going to help (as they show in movies). Say you are reciting mantra to attract $10 Million and constantly buying lottery tickets and intensely trying to manifest it (you have a chance). You see, the intensity and belief is the key and the mantras power and channel that intensity to manifest as desired.

Note: just because I did not refer to an authentic source doesn't mean I challenge our Hindu texts, if I find it, I'll come back to update it here.

Note to moderators - Respectfully, I do not see how much I could back my general knowledge by authentic sources. It is important to understand that Hinduism or in fact any other religion was not born out of authentic sources. Let me put it this way, not every answer comes out of a book. However, we could always validate if that answer makes sense, does it serves the purpose. So I request moderators to re-consider before marking my posts for delete. Also, for the practices that were passed on from my ancestors needs no citation, Thank you.

Comment: How do you know Hinduism was not "..born out of authentic sources.", whatever that means? Hinduism is the only remenant religion which has such a vast quantity of texts, that the possibility, however remote, of having every answer in it could even exist! Read my answer.

Comment: To answer your question, I wasn't challenging our sacred Hindu texts, including the source you referred Vivekacūḍāmaṇi. And about your answer which is half of my answer  and yet challenges core of Hinduism i.e., mantras won't work so my question back to you why are we reciting mantras in temples, performing puja. However I believe you interpreted incorrectly what Sri Adishankaracharya message, please refer to this interpretation https://antarmukhananda.org/Chitta-Shuddhi.html However, you could do better to make your answer relevant.

Comment: We do mantras because our biological brains cannot survice without doing so, it is status quo in equillibrium. Man+tra, in sanskrit grammar 'tra' suffix is used where we want to say "..that which arises from". 'Man' is root word for think/thought. Man+tra or Mantra is that which arises from thinking - a concept, an idea, a solution. Same with tantra (that which arises from your body-usage) and yantra (that which arises from holding/supporting). That is Panini's grammer.

Comment: What we do each & every day when we use our brains is nothing but Mantras. Until we realize this, we arent doing any mantra-japa, instead we are all doing smaraNa only. We use specifically (i.e. bhrama rahita) constructed sentences (what we colloquially call 'mantras' these days) and do repititions in our minds to train our subconscious mind; which then changes our internal outlooks or brings in internal changes; which then lead to how we see/view the outer world. That is the benefit of mantras.

Comment: You can sort of think of them as what we call 'mental affirmations' these days, and way better ones at that. But that is only a poor comparision. Knowing grammar I wrote my answer, not repeating others' views from blogs. You said sources don't exist, which I proved to be false. You can however, improve your answer by quoting sources to make it relevant.